# Email Attachments not working with Postmark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, email-attachments, postmark

I am using postmark to send email from the application. Its working fine for normal emails, but the email attachments are not working.

It works fine on local, as on local i have the smtp+postmark settings (as to work it on local we need to have postmark along with smtp)

But on staging and production am using only SMTP settings

**config/environments/staging.rb** and **config/environments/production.rb**

```
POSTMARK_API_KEY = "<my-api-key>"
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => POSTMARK_API_KEY }
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
POSTMARK_API_KEY = "<my-api-key>"
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.postmarkapp.com",
  :port                 => 25,
  :domain               => 'example.com',
  :user_name            => POSTMARK_API_KEY,
  :password             => POSTMARK_API_KEY,
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: DEFAULT_EMAIL

  def send_request(params, attachment)
     if attachment.present?
       mime_type = MIME::Types.type_for(attachment).first
       attachments["#{attachment.split('/').last}"] = { mime_type: mime_type,
         content: attachment, encoding: 'base64' }
     end

     mail(
       to:       <some_email>,
       subject:  "Refer Request",
       tag:      "refer_request")
  end
```

Here `attachment` is the url of file saved on S3.
In development mode i receive email with attachment.
but not in staging and development mode.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally am able to find the actual cause of above issue.

I am using the gem [postmark-rails](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails), previously postmark was not supporting the email-attachments, so recently they had enhanced gem to support attachments and unfortunately i was using the old version of it, so i need to update gem version to latest as they have mentioned in one of their issues: [attachment-issue](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails/issues/25)

also i was trying to send url of file saved on S3, so instead of that i need to read that file from url and then send it as attachment

```
  require "open-uri"

  def send_refer_pt_request(params, attachment)

    if attachment.present?
      mime_type = MIME::Types.type_for(attachment).first
      url_data = open(attachment).read()
      attachments["#{attachment.split('/').last}"] = { mime_type: mime_type,
        content: url_data }
    end

    mail(
      to:      <some_email>,
      subject: "Refer Request",
      tag:     "refer_request")
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

#### To send an email with attachment using Postmark Api

**This approach is using curl command.**

Require to get the remote file content

```
require "open-uri"
```

Require to get the encoding-decoding methods

```
require "base64"
```

Pass your remote file url to get the content of that

```
file_data  = open('https://example.com/dummy.pdf').read
```

Encryp the bin object to send it via email

```
encrypt_data   = Base64.encode64(file_data)
```

You can now send the email with attachment using postmark api and make sure to pass your API-KEY in the X-Postmark-Server-Token

```
system "curl -X POST \"http://api.postmarkapp.com/email\" \
-H \"Accept: application/json\" \
-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \
-H \"X-Postmark-Server-Token: POSTMARK_API_KEY\” \
-v \
-d \"{From: 'from@example.com', To: 'to@example.com', Subject: 'Postmark test for Attachment Email',  HtmlBody: '<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user you have received email with attachment.</body></html>', Attachments:[{'ContentType': 'application/pdf', 'Name': 'dummy.pdf', 'Content': '#{encrypt_data}'}]}\""
```